# How to make specific background task in Django?

Tags: python, django, celery, task

I have a mission to make a background task in Django, I tried with celery but I didn't have success.
What I have to do? I need after the person wrote the number in input and pressed submit button, for example 100, the 1% of it will be added every second to his previous number during the 1 day.

1. He wrote in input 100
2. In database this is stored, and in during a day, every second is adding 1%.
3. How concretely it looks, 100+1=101, 101+1=102, 102+1.... every second adding 1%

Can you help me draw the code what it looks like? With celery, django-background-task or others doesn't matter, the main importance that it needs to be certain number of tasks simultaneously, for every user his background task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a package called `django-background-tasks`

and your function will be like this:

```
from background_task import background

@background(schedule=60)
def add(input): # this function will run every 60 seconds
    input += (input*0.01)
```

link for the package [docs](https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: I get it, thanks. How can I call this task specifically for 1day. Actually I have a thought, for example, when user press the button, I will add this user in a "this" group for 1 day, if he is in "this" group, it will trigger the task, and it will work. Do you think it's good way to do it?

Comment: ya, it's good for your case.if my answer helped you please upvote to motivate me more to help people :).

Comment: I have also a question, can I make this background task while the user is not on website? I will be glad to hear the answer